# Displaying column labels from a Matrix field

Tags: matrix

Is there's a way to display column labels from a Matrix field in templates?

```
{matrix_field}
{column:label} : {columnvalue}
{/matrix_field}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think you can. However, Matrix has a table tag that quickly creates a HTML table:

```
{my_matrix_field:table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"}
```

If that doesn't work, I suggest using conditionals to hard code the 'labels' within your template. I would have to see a sample of the code first to help with conditionals

Comment: That's really pity- I spent a lot of time trying to extract the labels. Table is good, but it doesn't give you flexibility